# C# WPF: Dependency Property vs MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to create a component with Dependency Property, I don´t know how to bind the data from another user control, can someone explain it to me? I don´t think i need to create a viewmodel for the component.

Here´s my code:

Here I call the component

```
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <ctrls:CustomComboBox Collection="{Binding Path=TestingCollection}" SelectedCollectionItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
                              CreateCommand="" DeleteCommand="" UpdateCommand=""/>
    </DockPanel>
```

And Here it´s my component

```
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCollectionItem,ElementName=CustomComboBoxControl, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                  SelectedValuePath="Name"
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                  />
```

Here it is my xaml.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Collection", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(CustomComboBox));

public ObservableCollection<object> Collection
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(CollectionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CollectionProperty, value); }
}



public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCollectionItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedCollectionItem", typeof(object), typeof(CustomComboBox));
public object SelectedCollectionItem
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedCollectionItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedCollectionItemProperty, value); }
}
```

EDIT:

I tryed creating a VM and setting the data context, and works, but dependency properties seem pointless

EDIT 2:

I succeded, i delete my VM i was lacking and ElementName in ItemSource

Comment: Any reason why you don't derive from ComboBox? Anyway, when you have `ElementName=CustomComboBoxControl` on the SelectedValue Binding, why not on the ItemsSource Binding?

Comment: I ommit the code parts where I add 3 buttons to the code. I tryed to make it as short as possible.

Comment: UserControls do not need private view models. Assuming that `CustomComboBoxControl` is the `x:Name` of the UserControl, you have already done it right with setting the ElementName in the SelectedValue Binding. Do the same for the ItemsSource Binding. Alternatively, write `ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`.

Answer (score -1):

I succeded, i delete my VM i was lacking and ElementName in ItemSource